# Determine if matrix exists or not

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

any help with optimizing following code to make it run faster.

Tried making function inline, tried cin.TIE(NULL), tried ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class gfg
{
public:
bool satisfiable(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b) {
  while (!a.empty()) {
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(), std::greater<int>());
    int k = a.back();
    a.pop_back();
    if (k > b.size()) return false;
    if (k == 0) continue;
    if (b[k - 1] == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
      b[i]--;
  }
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); i++)
    if (*i != 0)
      return false;
  return true;
}

};


int main()
{
    gfg g;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int r,c,n,cnt=0;
    cin >> n;
    while(cnt<n){
        cnt++;
    cin >> r >> c;
    int x;
      vector<int> a;
      vector<int> b;
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
            cin >> x;
          a.push_back(x);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
          cin >> x;
          b.push_back(x);
    }



    if(g.satisfiable(a,b)) cout << "YES\n";
    else cout << "NO\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected : Average 1s or less processing time per test case Actual : Average 2s to 2.5s processing time per test case

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This question is currently a "code dump". Please explain what task this code accomplishes. See [ask].

Comment: Did you try using a profiler? What did it say was taking up the time? Also, it would help to see an example of the input data.

Comment: As is typical with any performance related question, _are you compiling with optimizations enabled_?

Answer (score 5):

General points:

- We need to include `<functional>` for `std::greater<>`.
- [Don't do `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- The `gfg` class has no state, so we can use a free function for `satisfiable`.
- Variables should be declared as close as possible to their point of use. If possible they should also be initialized to a valid value, and not a placeholder "invalid value". e.g. `r`, and `c` should be declared inside the outer `while` loop.
- Reading input can be made much neater by factoring it into a separate function. We should also check for errors by testing `cin.fail()`.

Performance:

- There is no need to modify the vector `a`. We are just iterating through it in reverse, which can be done with... reverse iterators:

  ```
  for (auto r = a.rbegin(); r != a.rend(); ++r) { int k = *r; ... }
  ```
- This means that `satisfiable` can take `a` by const reference and avoid copying it:

  ```
  bool satisfiable(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> b) { ... }
  ```
- The vector `b` is modified inside the function, so we should still accept the parameter by value. However, since we don't use the vector in `main` afterwards we can still avoid copying it:

  ```
  satisfiable(a, std::move(b))
  ```

Modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool satisfiable(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> b) {

    for (auto r = a.rbegin(); r != a.rend(); ++r) {

        std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(), std::greater<int>());

        int k = *r;

        if (k > b.size()) return false;
        if (k == 0) continue;
        if (b[k - 1] == 0) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i != k; ++i)
            b[i]--;
    }

    auto is_zero = [] (int x) { return x == 0; };
    return std::all_of(b.begin(), b.end(), is_zero);
}

int read_int()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "invalid input!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);

    int n = read_int();

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt != n; ++cnt) {

        int r = read_int();
        int c = read_int();

        std::vector<int> a;
        for (int i = 0; i != r; ++i)
            a.push_back(read_int());

        std::vector<int> b;
        for (int j = 0; j != c; ++j)
            b.push_back(read_int());

        std::cout << (satisfiable(a, std::move(b)) ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";
    }
}
```

These changes may not fix your performance issues. I suspect that with large inputs, most of the time will be taken up by `std::sort` (you should profile it and find out!). Without more details on what the algorithm does, or what the input looks like, it's hard to make further suggestions.

However, it looks like we don't need to sort the entire `b` vector with every iteration:

- If the item at `k-1` is greater than the item at `k` before the decrement, it will be equal to the item at `k` after the decrement (i.e. the `b` vector is still sorted correctly).
- If the item at `k-1` is equal to the item at `k` before the decrement, it will be less than the item at `k` after the decrement (i.e. the `b` vector is no longer ordered).

  However, we still don't need to sort the whole vector, we can just move any equal items from `k` onwards to the correct point (perhaps using [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)). In this case you may also find the [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) algorithms useful.

Comment: The Idea behind the program is to tell whether a matrix exists or not (yes or no) given list of values in each row and column
For ex.

3 2  - dimensions
2 1 0 - row values
1 2 - col values
YES (Matrix Exists)



3 3  - dimensions
3 2 1 - row values
1 2 2 - col values
NO(Matrix wont Exists)

Comment: I tried above modified code by you ( with all suggested improvements by you however i was not able to get performance below 2s average, seems like the sort is bottelneck). maybe i am trying the wrong approach while sorting or doing it in wrong way can you please show the kind of sorting you are takling about.